# Problem with keystrokes in Cloud Firestore Rules editor

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-console

I just returned to edit some rules in the Cloud Firestore Rules editor in the Firebase web console. To my surprise I am not able to mark a part of the code (for cut-and-paste). Neither mouse nor keyboard keys works for this. (Ctrl-A does not work either. So I can't edit the code somewhere else.)

I can't remember that this did not work before. Does it work for you?

This is in Chrome Version 97.0.4692.71 (Official Build) (64-bit) latest Windows 10.

Comment: It's working for me. Version 97.0.4692.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: This is going be hard for anyone to provide an answer beyond "yes" or "no". I recommend checking the JavaScript console of your browser for any relevant error messages, disabling any extensions you may have running, and trying in a different browser and/or on a different network. If none of those work, it might be good to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, of course. But now it is working again. However the colors used for the CSS selection are very subtle. I wonder if someone accidently made them too subtle.  (I really recommend to make the selection color stand out a bit more.)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking the JavaScript console of your browser for any relevant error messages, disabling any extensions you may have running, and trying in a different browser and/or on a different network. If none of those work, it might be good to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.